# why I can not permanently remove a file from linux?

Tags: linux, file

Today,I encounter a very tough problem which cost me nearly 6 hours.

When I remove a file called ha_wan.conf using **rm -rf ha_wan.conf** command under /etc directory,Success.When I use **ls -al** command to see the result,The file disappear.

But when I reboot the linux system,same file named ha_wan.conf come back,located under /etc/ directory.

I tried to delete it many many times,It is the same result.

What should I do,I want to permanently remove that file.Thanks.

Comment: why do you want to delete it?  you will need to find whats auto creating it.  which linux?  and any idea what the ha portion of ha_wan stands for?

Comment: It's called **H**igh **A**vailability for a reason

Comment: Alternatively to removing the file, empty the contents out, and chattr +i the file, then whatever is creating it won't be able to put it's data in there. 
But better then that, find the root cause (what creates the file?) and stop or reconfigure that service.

Answer (score 2):

There's no magic. You removed the file. If you still see it after a reboot, it means one of two things:

1. (very likely) Some service recreates the files on boot, or periodically. You can probably use standard system tools to find out which package contained that file. (for example `dpkg -S ha_wan.conf` in debian-like systems)
2. (unlikely) You're running some interesting system which uses a temporary filesystem in /etc. If you're using a standard desktop distribution, that's improbable. But if it's some kind of router / special device, then it could happen.

Comment: viraptor,Thank you very much..It is the case 2.After I rewrite the root filesystem.the file gone.